# How to put button to mat-table in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mat-table

I want to put a delete button or Angular trash icon to a `mat-table` in Angular. How can i achieve it?
My working table code:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="ELEMENT_DATA">
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="40%">Position</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="40%">{{config.position}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="30%">Label</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="30%">{{config.name}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="10%">Order</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="10%">{{config.weight}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="symbol">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="10%">Symbol</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="10%">{{config.symbol}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *cdkRowDef="let config; columns: displayedColumns;"
           (click)="editConfig(config.id)"></mat-row>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an extra column for that, for example:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol','deleteAction'];
```

and to use in Mat-Table:

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="deleteAction">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><i class="material-icons" (click)="delete(element)">delete</i>
</ng-container>
```

A working [`StackBlitz Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxjlnf)

Answer (score 2):

Add this button to another mat-cell.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="delete()"> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```